# Problem with .htaccess accessing variable in method in PHP with forward slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a problem accessing a variable.

My method is requested this way:

```
http://example.com/method/parameter
```

I have a specific `.htaccess` file that manages that:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?categoryId=$1 [QSA,L] 
</ifmodule>
```

This enables the `$categoryId` variable to be passed by a forward slash.

Here is the deal, I'm trying to pass another variable adding another forward slash. The complete request would be something like this:

```
http://example.com/method/parameter/orderby
```

I've tried changing the `.htaccess` file to:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?categoryId=$1?orderBy=$2 [QSA,L] 
</ifmodule>
```

There was no change. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do to capture multiple query string parameters in the `$_GET` array in `index.php` is change your `RewriteRule` to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?method=$1&param=$2&orderby=$3 [L,QSA]
```

I've used `method`, `param` and `orderby` as you indicated in the question.

Just repeat the pattern `([^/]+)/` for each query string parameter you want to add, and reference them respectively with `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.

**Note:** in your original  `RewriteRule` you did not format the query string properly, you need to use `&` between the parameters, not `?`(the question mark is used as a separator, and is not part of the query string.).

The above solution requires three parameters, if however you wanted to make the parameters optional, you can use `?` in the pattern, as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?categoryId=$1&orderBy=$2&something=$3 [L,QSA]
```

A question mark makes a preceding token in the regular expression optional.